# What to do with a singular fit with gls in R ? (mixed effect model and nested factors)

Tags: r, mixed-model, nested-data, generalized-least-squares, singular-matrix

I am new to these kind of statistics and I don't understand the error I get since the same code worked before on an other set of data (with different levels in the factors).

Here is my design. I have 3 factors: Substrate (4 levels); Origin (5 levels); and Genotype (18 levels). Genotype is nested in Origin.

I want to know if there is an effect of Origin on the measured variable (shannon) OR an effect of Genotype. I also need to know if there is an interaction between Substrate and Origin (or Genotype).

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a3TN-Zg9sVPf7LDVsR6AjZuQ3NF0leOE/view?usp=sharing) is my data.

I used gls because I need to include weights to take into acount the overal effect of Substrate on the variance of the data. Here is my model and the error it gives:

```
mod <- gls(shannon ~ Substrate:Origin + Substrate + Origin,
           weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1|Substrate),
           correlation = corCompSymm(form = ~ Genotype|Origin),
           data = my_data,
           na.action = "na.omit")

Error in glsEstimate(object, control = control) : 
  computed "gls" fit is singular, rank 18
```

When I remove the interaction term the model runs properly, however, as I said, I realy need this term.

When searching for this error, I found that it may be because of overfitting. Is there another way I could calculate the effect of the interaction term?

NOTE: There are only two missing values and the dataset meets the parametric assumptions. Also, there are 3 reps for every combination of Genotype:Substrate (except for the two missing values).

**EDIT**

I can ignore the singularity to produce a summary and make an anova.

```
mod <- gls(shannon ~ Substrate:Origin + Substrate + Origin,
           weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1|Substrate),
           correlation = corCompSymm(form = ~ Genotype|Origin),
           data = my_data,
           method = "REML",
           na.action = "na.omit",
           control = list(singular.ok = TRUE))
```

Here is the summary

```
Generalized least squares fit by REML
  Model: shannon ~ Substrate:Origin + Substrate + Origin 
  Data: my_data 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  325.4394 402.3188 -137.7197

Correlation Structure: Compound symmetry
 Formula: ~Genotype | Origin 
 Parameter estimate(s):
         Rho 
3.397167e-18 
Variance function:
 Structure: Different standard deviations per stratum
 Formula: ~1 | Substrate 
 Parameter estimates:
NA.Waste.Rock       Control  A.Waste.Rock      Tailings 
            1             1             1             1 

Coefficients:
                                               Value Std.Error  t-value p-value
(Intercept)                                 6.601569 0.1684757 39.18409  0.0000
SubstrateControl                           -0.136807 0.2382607 -0.57419  0.5666
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock                     -0.411788 0.2455935 -1.67671  0.0956
SubstrateTailings                           0.319328 0.2382607  1.34025  0.1821
OriginEastern                              -0.230572 0.2455935 -0.93884  0.3492
OriginLa.Corne.Mine                        -0.108815 0.2228725 -0.48824  0.6260
OriginWestern                              -0.081117 0.2131068 -0.38064  0.7040
OriginWestwood                             -0.073239 0.2382607 -0.30739  0.7589
SubstrateControl:OriginEastern             -0.263073 0.3421759 -0.76882  0.4431
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginEastern        0.304783 0.3473217  0.87752  0.3815
SubstrateControl:OriginLa.Corne.Mine       -0.072767 0.3151893 -0.23087  0.8177
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginLa.Corne.Mine  0.020410 0.3207683  0.06363  0.9493
SubstrateTailings:OriginLa.Corne.Mine       0.077623 0.3151893  0.24628  0.8058
SubstrateControl:OriginWestern             -0.320295 0.3033900 -1.05572  0.2927
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginWestern       -0.030207 0.3072085 -0.09833  0.9218
SubstrateControl:OriginWestwood            -0.187284 0.3369515 -0.55582  0.5791
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginWestwood      -0.047583 0.3421759 -0.13906  0.8896

 Correlation: 
                                           (Intr) SbstrC SbNA.W.R SbstrT OrgnEs
SubstrateControl                           -0.707                              
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock                     -0.686  0.485                       
SubstrateTailings                           0.000  0.000  0.000                
OriginEastern                              -0.686  0.485  0.471    0.000       
OriginLa.Corne.Mine                        -0.756  0.535  0.519    0.000  0.519
OriginWestern                              -0.791  0.559  0.542    0.000  0.542
OriginWestwood                             -0.707  0.500  0.485   -0.500  0.485
SubstrateControl:OriginEastern              0.492 -0.696 -0.338    0.000 -0.718
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginEastern        0.485 -0.343 -0.707    0.000 -0.707
SubstrateControl:OriginLa.Corne.Mine        0.535 -0.756 -0.367    0.000 -0.367
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginLa.Corne.Mine  0.525 -0.371 -0.766    0.000 -0.360
SubstrateTailings:OriginLa.Corne.Mine       0.000  0.000  0.000   -0.756  0.000
SubstrateControl:OriginWestern              0.555 -0.785 -0.381    0.000 -0.381
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginWestern        0.548 -0.388 -0.799    0.000 -0.376
SubstrateControl:OriginWestwood             0.500 -0.707 -0.343    0.354 -0.343
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginWestwood       0.492 -0.348 -0.718    0.348 -0.338
                                           OL.C.M OrgnWstr OrgnWstw SbC:OE
SubstrateControl                                                          
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock                                                    
SubstrateTailings                                                         
OriginEastern                                                             
OriginLa.Corne.Mine                                                       
OriginWestern                               0.598                         
OriginWestwood                              0.535  0.559                  
SubstrateControl:OriginEastern             -0.372 -0.389   -0.348         
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginEastern       -0.367 -0.383   -0.343    0.508
SubstrateControl:OriginLa.Corne.Mine       -0.707 -0.423   -0.378    0.526
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginLa.Corne.Mine -0.695 -0.415   -0.371    0.259
SubstrateTailings:OriginLa.Corne.Mine      -0.303  0.000    0.378    0.000
SubstrateControl:OriginWestern             -0.420 -0.702   -0.393    0.547
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginWestern       -0.415 -0.694   -0.388    0.270
SubstrateControl:OriginWestwood            -0.378 -0.395   -0.707    0.492
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginWestwood      -0.372 -0.389   -0.696    0.242
                                           SNA.W.R:OE SC:OL. SNA.W.R:OL ST:OL.
SubstrateControl                                                              
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock                                                        
SubstrateTailings                                                             
OriginEastern                                                                 
OriginLa.Corne.Mine                                                           
OriginWestern                                                                 
OriginWestwood                                                                
SubstrateControl:OriginEastern                                                
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginEastern                                          
SubstrateControl:OriginLa.Corne.Mine        0.259                             
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginLa.Corne.Mine  0.541      0.491                  
SubstrateTailings:OriginLa.Corne.Mine       0.000      0.214  0.211           
SubstrateControl:OriginWestern              0.269      0.594  0.292      0.000
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginWestern        0.565      0.293  0.612      0.000
SubstrateControl:OriginWestwood             0.243      0.535  0.263     -0.267
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginWestwood       0.508      0.263  0.550     -0.263
                                           SbstrtCntrl:OrgnWstr
SubstrateControl                                               
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock                                         
SubstrateTailings                                              
OriginEastern                                                  
OriginLa.Corne.Mine                                            
OriginWestern                                                  
OriginWestwood                                                 
SubstrateControl:OriginEastern                                 
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginEastern                           
SubstrateControl:OriginLa.Corne.Mine                           
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginLa.Corne.Mine                     
SubstrateTailings:OriginLa.Corne.Mine                          
SubstrateControl:OriginWestern                                 
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginWestern        0.487              
SubstrateControl:OriginWestwood             0.555              
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginWestwood       0.273              
                                           SbstrtNA.Wst.Rck:OrgnWstr
SubstrateControl                                                    
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock                                              
SubstrateTailings                                                   
OriginEastern                                                       
OriginLa.Corne.Mine                                                 
OriginWestern                                                       
OriginWestwood                                                      
SubstrateControl:OriginEastern                                      
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginEastern                                
SubstrateControl:OriginLa.Corne.Mine                                
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginLa.Corne.Mine                          
SubstrateTailings:OriginLa.Corne.Mine                               
SubstrateControl:OriginWestern                                      
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginWestern                                
SubstrateControl:OriginWestwood             0.274                   
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginWestwood       0.574                   
                                           SbstrtCntrl:OrgnWstw
SubstrateControl                                               
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock                                         
SubstrateTailings                                              
OriginEastern                                                  
OriginLa.Corne.Mine                                            
OriginWestern                                                  
OriginWestwood                                                 
SubstrateControl:OriginEastern                                 
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginEastern                           
SubstrateControl:OriginLa.Corne.Mine                           
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginLa.Corne.Mine                     
SubstrateTailings:OriginLa.Corne.Mine                          
SubstrateControl:OriginWestern                                 
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginWestern                           
SubstrateControl:OriginWestwood                                
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginWestwood       0.492              

Standardized residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-2.40142528 -0.62227095  0.07345434  0.58031803  2.11407668 

Residual standard error: 0.5054272 
Degrees of freedom: 180 total; 160 residual
```

Here is the anova

```
Denom. DF: 160 
                 numDF   F-value p-value
(Intercept)          1 28368.157  <.0001
Substrate            3    14.268  <.0001
Origin               4     0.816  0.5168
Substrate:Origin    12        NA      NA
Warning message:
In print.anova.lme(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

**SECOND EDIT**

Here is the model with `lme()` instead of `gls()` and the error. I don't know how to bypass that error.

```
mod <- lme(shannon ~ Substrate:Origin,
           random = ~ 1 | Origin/Genotype,
           weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1|Substrate),
           data = my_data,
           na.action = "na.omit")

Error in MEEM(object, conLin, control$niterEM) : 
  Singularity in backsolve at level 0, block 1
```

**THIRD EDIT**

Here is the result for the model with `gls()` whitout the correlation.
Note : I get the same error and need to bypass it with `control = list(singular.ok = TRUE)`.

````
Generalized least squares fit by REML
  Model: shannon ~ Substrate:Origin + Substrate + Origin 
  Data: my_data 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  323.4394 397.2436 -137.7197

Variance function:
 Structure: Different standard deviations per stratum
 Formula: ~1 | Substrate 
 Parameter estimates:
NA.Waste.Rock  A.Waste.Rock       Control      Tailings 
            1             1             1             1 

Coefficients:
                                               Value Std.Error  t-value p-value
(Intercept)                                 6.601569 0.1684757 39.18409  0.0000
SubstrateControl                           -0.136807 0.2382607 -0.57419  0.5666
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock                     -0.411788 0.2455935 -1.67671  0.0956
SubstrateTailings                           0.319328 0.2382607  1.34025  0.1821
OriginEastern                              -0.230572 0.2455935 -0.93884  0.3492
OriginLa.Corne.Mine                        -0.108815 0.2228725 -0.48824  0.6260
OriginWestern                              -0.081117 0.2131068 -0.38064  0.7040
OriginWestwood                             -0.073239 0.2382607 -0.30739  0.7589
SubstrateControl:OriginEastern             -0.263073 0.3421759 -0.76882  0.4431
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginEastern        0.304783 0.3473217  0.87752  0.3815
SubstrateControl:OriginLa.Corne.Mine       -0.072767 0.3151893 -0.23087  0.8177
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginLa.Corne.Mine  0.020410 0.3207683  0.06363  0.9493
SubstrateTailings:OriginLa.Corne.Mine       0.077623 0.3151893  0.24628  0.8058
SubstrateControl:OriginWestern             -0.320295 0.3033900 -1.05572  0.2927
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginWestern       -0.030207 0.3072085 -0.09833  0.9218
SubstrateControl:OriginWestwood            -0.187284 0.3369515 -0.55582  0.5791
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginWestwood      -0.047583 0.3421759 -0.13906  0.8896

 Correlation: 
                                           (Intr) SbstrC SbNA.W.R SbstrT OrgnEs
SubstrateControl                           -0.707                              
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock                     -0.686  0.485                       
SubstrateTailings                           0.000  0.000  0.000                
OriginEastern                              -0.686  0.485  0.471    0.000       
OriginLa.Corne.Mine                        -0.756  0.535  0.519    0.000  0.519
OriginWestern                              -0.791  0.559  0.542    0.000  0.542
OriginWestwood                             -0.707  0.500  0.485   -0.500  0.485
SubstrateControl:OriginEastern              0.492 -0.696 -0.338    0.000 -0.718
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginEastern        0.485 -0.343 -0.707    0.000 -0.707
SubstrateControl:OriginLa.Corne.Mine        0.535 -0.756 -0.367    0.000 -0.367
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginLa.Corne.Mine  0.525 -0.371 -0.766    0.000 -0.360
SubstrateTailings:OriginLa.Corne.Mine       0.000  0.000  0.000   -0.756  0.000
SubstrateControl:OriginWestern              0.555 -0.785 -0.381    0.000 -0.381
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginWestern        0.548 -0.388 -0.799    0.000 -0.376
SubstrateControl:OriginWestwood             0.500 -0.707 -0.343    0.354 -0.343
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginWestwood       0.492 -0.348 -0.718    0.348 -0.338
                                           OL.C.M OrgnWstr OrgnWstw SbC:OE
SubstrateControl                                                          
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock                                                    
SubstrateTailings                                                         
OriginEastern                                                             
OriginLa.Corne.Mine                                                       
OriginWestern                               0.598                         
OriginWestwood                              0.535  0.559                  
SubstrateControl:OriginEastern             -0.372 -0.389   -0.348         
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginEastern       -0.367 -0.383   -0.343    0.508
SubstrateControl:OriginLa.Corne.Mine       -0.707 -0.423   -0.378    0.526
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginLa.Corne.Mine -0.695 -0.415   -0.371    0.259
SubstrateTailings:OriginLa.Corne.Mine      -0.303  0.000    0.378    0.000
SubstrateControl:OriginWestern             -0.420 -0.702   -0.393    0.547
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginWestern       -0.415 -0.694   -0.388    0.270
SubstrateControl:OriginWestwood            -0.378 -0.395   -0.707    0.492
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginWestwood      -0.372 -0.389   -0.696    0.242
                                           SNA.W.R:OE SC:OL. SNA.W.R:OL ST:OL.
SubstrateControl                                                              
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock                                                        
SubstrateTailings                                                             
OriginEastern                                                                 
OriginLa.Corne.Mine                                                           
OriginWestern                                                                 
OriginWestwood                                                                
SubstrateControl:OriginEastern                                                
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginEastern                                          
SubstrateControl:OriginLa.Corne.Mine        0.259                             
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginLa.Corne.Mine  0.541      0.491                  
SubstrateTailings:OriginLa.Corne.Mine       0.000      0.214  0.211           
SubstrateControl:OriginWestern              0.269      0.594  0.292      0.000
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginWestern        0.565      0.293  0.612      0.000
SubstrateControl:OriginWestwood             0.243      0.535  0.263     -0.267
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginWestwood       0.508      0.263  0.550     -0.263
                                           SbstrtCntrl:OrgnWstr
SubstrateControl                                               
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock                                         
SubstrateTailings                                              
OriginEastern                                                  
OriginLa.Corne.Mine                                            
OriginWestern                                                  
OriginWestwood                                                 
SubstrateControl:OriginEastern                                 
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginEastern                           
SubstrateControl:OriginLa.Corne.Mine                           
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginLa.Corne.Mine                     
SubstrateTailings:OriginLa.Corne.Mine                          
SubstrateControl:OriginWestern                                 
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginWestern        0.487              
SubstrateControl:OriginWestwood             0.555              
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginWestwood       0.273              
                                           SbstrtNA.Wst.Rck:OrgnWstr
SubstrateControl                                                    
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock                                              
SubstrateTailings                                                   
OriginEastern                                                       
OriginLa.Corne.Mine                                                 
OriginWestern                                                       
OriginWestwood                                                      
SubstrateControl:OriginEastern                                      
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginEastern                                
SubstrateControl:OriginLa.Corne.Mine                                
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginLa.Corne.Mine                          
SubstrateTailings:OriginLa.Corne.Mine                               
SubstrateControl:OriginWestern                                      
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginWestern                                
SubstrateControl:OriginWestwood             0.274                   
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginWestwood       0.574                   
                                           SbstrtCntrl:OrgnWstw
SubstrateControl                                               
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock                                         
SubstrateTailings                                              
OriginEastern                                                  
OriginLa.Corne.Mine                                            
OriginWestern                                                  
OriginWestwood                                                 
SubstrateControl:OriginEastern                                 
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginEastern                           
SubstrateControl:OriginLa.Corne.Mine                           
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginLa.Corne.Mine                     
SubstrateTailings:OriginLa.Corne.Mine                          
SubstrateControl:OriginWestern                                 
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginWestern                           
SubstrateControl:OriginWestwood                                
SubstrateNA.Waste.Rock:OriginWestwood       0.492              

Standardized residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-2.40142528 -0.62227095  0.07345434  0.58031803  2.11407668 

Residual standard error: 0.5054272 
Degrees of freedom: 180 total; 160 residual
```
````

Comment: Please provide the model output (summary).

Comment: Also, is there a reason you don't use `lme()` ?

Comment: There is no model produced because of the error. However, if I added in the EDIT the model with `control = list(singular.ok = TRUE)`. Also, I tried to use lme() and lmer() but I get the same error.

Comment: Ahh, ok. Well in `lmer` a singular fit is not an error, it's a warning, so you can output the summary - could you do that instead please ?

Comment: Also, I used `gls()` beacuse I don't think I can use `weights` the way I intend to with `lme()` and `lmer()`.

Comment: For `lmer` I agree but I thought `lme` handled weights in the same way (I might be wrong as I don't often use `gls`)? Anyway, thanks for posting the output. It is telling you that you may not need to specify compond symmetry - because the correlation is being estimated very close to zero. I would try removing it and see if the estimates of interested (fixed effects) change meaninfully. If not, then just proceed without it (go back to `gls` or `lme` and remove the term from there). Let us know if that works and I will write an actual answer a bit later.

Comment: One other thing to check: does `lm(shannon ~ Substrate:Origin + Substrate + Origin, data = my_data)` fit without warnings or errors or strange output ?

Comment: I tried `lm(shannon ~ Substrate:Origin + Substrate + Origin, data = my_data)` and there is no error.

I tried `lme()` and it does accept `weights` the way I specified it. I will add that output to a second EDIT.

I don't understand what you ask me to do. What exactly am I suppose to remove?

Comment: OK that's good (about `lm`) - that just rules out a problem with fixed effects. What I'm asking you to remove is `correlation = corCompSymm(form = ~ Genotype|Origin)`

Comment: I added a third edit with the gls model excluding the correlation. Is there an other way in gls I can specify genotype is nested in origin?

Comment: I don't really use `gls`. I would use `lme`. Note that in your `lme` model you need `shannon ~ Substrate*Origin` whch fits the main effects and interaction not  `Substrate:Origin` which is just the interaction. As for nesting `Genotype` in `Origin`, since `Origin` is a fixed effect you wouldn't want `random = ~ 1 | Origin/Genotype` because that will also fit random intercepts for `Origin`. Instead use `1 | Origin:Genotype` and compare that to `1 | Genotype`

Comment: I tried what you specified for `lme` and I get this error : `Error in getGroups.data.frame(dataMix, groups) : 
  invalid formula for groups`

Comment: Please post the whole `lme` formula here.

Comment: mod <- lme(shannon ~ Substrate*Origin,
           random = ~ 1 | Origin:Genotype,
           weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1|Substrate),
           data = my_data,
           na.action = "na.omit")

Comment: Ahh :(  try `my_data$OG <- interaction(my_data$Origin, my_data$Genotype)` then `mod <- lme(shannon ~ Substrate*Origin, random = ~ 1 | OG, weights =  ....`

Comment: Thank you, it solve that error, but I still get the original error : `Error in MEEM(object, conLin, control$niterEM) : 
  Singularity in backsolve at level 0, block 1`. And for `lme` I don't know how to bypass that error.

Comment: Oh dear :(  does `...random = ~ 1 | Genotype, ... ` work ? Also, does `lmer(shannon ~ Substrate*Origin + (1 | Origin:Genotype)` work ? I know you want weights but there is something weird going on which is easier to debug in `lmer`

Comment: `...random = ~ 1 | Genotype, ...` does not work in `lme`, but `lmer(shannon ~ Substrate*Origin + (1 | Origin:Genotype), data = my_data)` does work with a warning message: `fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 3 columns / coefficients
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110655/discussion-between-robert-long-and-karelle-rheault).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue in this case is that the experiment was factorial in nature but due to some unobserved combinations of one level of one of the variables with another, the design matrix for the fixed effects was rank deficient. ie it was an incomplete